# Placeholder color in Dark mode from Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I want to change the place holder color by setting the key path value from user defined runtime attribute and assign a custom color but it has no effect on placeholder color 
the value I set is as below
[image]

Please help I need this from storyboard instead of code

Comment: PlaceholderLabel is a label ?

Comment: Placeholder is a label in Textfield @jawadAli

Comment: done by using placeholderLabel.textColor instead of _placeholderLabel.textColor

Answer (score 0):

Use :

```
placeholderLabel.attributedPlaceholder
```

Answer (score 0):

use UITextField extension

```
    extension UITextField {
        func updatePlaceHolder(_ text: String, color: UIColor) {
            attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: text,
                                                       attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: color])
        }
    }
//color set for textfield placeholder 
textFieldNumber.updatePlaceHolder("Mobile Number", color: UIColor.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0.0980392, alpha: 0.22))
```